# studio quit unexpectedly. (android studio can not launch on macos) EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

Tags: macos, android-studio, crash-reports

lately I have updated my macOS to `13.0 (22A380)` and after updating android studio to `2021.3.1.17` [latest to this time].
I keep getting crash message when i try to open the app.
things I have tried:
here is an image and log that I get.

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               studio [1721]
Path:                  /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio
Identifier:            com.google.android.studio
Version:               2021.3 (AI-213.7172.25.2113.9123335)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2022-11-07 11:08:11.5742 +0330
OS Version:            macOS 13.0 (22A380)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     7.0 (20P411)
Anonymous UUID:        8AB98A6D-E4F5-28A2-20AE-42E6FA35B587


Time Awake Since Boot: 1800 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        3

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
abort() called


Application Specific Backtrace 0:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff80c36c43b __exceptionPreprocess + 242
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007ff80bebbe25 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff80c3945d6 _CFBundleGetValueForInfoKey + 0
3   AppKit                              0x00007ff80f43b161 -[NSWindow(NSWindow_Theme) _postWindowNeedsToResetDragMarginsUnlessPostingDisabled] + 307
4   AppKit                              0x00007ff80f427f4f -[NSWindow _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 1247
5   AppKit                              0x00007ff80f5c2412 -[NSPanel _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 50
6   AppKit                              0x00007ff80f427a69 -[NSWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 42
7   AppKit                              0x00007ff80f5c23cb -[NSPanel initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 59
8   AppKit                              0x00007ff80f425f88 -[NSWindowTemplate nibInstantiate] + 354
9   AppKit                              0x00007ff80f3f442a -[NSIBObjectData instantiateObject:] + 222
10  AppKit                              0x00007ff80f3f3b9c -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 476
11  AppKit                              0x00007ff80f3e867f loadNib + 420
12  AppKit                              0x00007ff80f3e7a67 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:options:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 737
13  AppKit                              0x00007ff80f3e7691 -[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:] + 201
14  AppKit                              0x00007ff80f73a7a0 -[NSAlert init] + 101
15  studio                              0x0000000101d43f6c parseVMOptions + 956
16  studio                              0x0000000101d431a6 -[Launcher buildArgsFor:] + 150
17  studio                              0x0000000101d43695 -[Launcher launch] + 453
18  Foundation                          0x00007ff80d14382c __NSThread__start__ + 1009
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff80c219259 _pthread_start + 125
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff80c214c7b thread_start + 15


Thread 0::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff80c1da6a2 mach_msg2_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff80c1e867d mach_msg2_internal + 82
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff80c1e171a mach_msg_overwrite + 723
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff80c1da989 mach_msg + 19
4   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff80c2f3d0e __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 145
5   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff80c2f277a __CFRunLoopRun + 1360
6   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff80c2f1bb0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 560
7   studio                                 0x101d42c71 parkRunLoop + 113
8   studio                                 0x101d42b53 main + 259
9   dyld                                0x7ff80bee8310 start + 2432

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80c214c58 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80c214c58 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff80c1e130e __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80c218f7b pthread_kill + 263
2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x7ff80c162ca5 abort + 123
3   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7ff80c1d3082 abort_message + 241
4   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7ff80c1c423d demangling_terminate_handler() + 266
5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x7ff80bec3023 _objc_terminate() + 96
6   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7ff80c1d24a5 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
7   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7ff80c1d4d05 __cxxabiv1::failed_throw(__cxxabiv1::__cxa_exception*) + 27
8   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7ff80c1d4ccc __cxa_throw + 116
9   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x7ff80bebbf23 objc_exception_throw + 302
10  CoreFoundation                      0x7ff80c3945d6 -[NSException raise] + 9
11  AppKit                              0x7ff80f43b161 -[NSWindow(NSWindow_Theme) _postWindowNeedsToResetDragMarginsUnlessPostingDisabled] + 307
12  AppKit                              0x7ff80f427f4f -[NSWindow _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 1247
13  AppKit                              0x7ff80f5c2412 -[NSPanel _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 50
14  AppKit                              0x7ff80f427a69 -[NSWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 42
15  AppKit                              0x7ff80f5c23cb -[NSPanel initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 59
16  AppKit                              0x7ff80f425f88 -[NSWindowTemplate nibInstantiate] + 354
17  AppKit                              0x7ff80f3f442a -[NSIBObjectData instantiateObject:] + 222
18  AppKit                              0x7ff80f3f3b9c -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 476
19  AppKit                              0x7ff80f3e867f loadNib + 420
20  AppKit                              0x7ff80f3e7a67 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:options:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 737
21  AppKit                              0x7ff80f3e7691 -[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:] + 201
22  AppKit                              0x7ff80f73a7a0 -[NSAlert init] + 101
23  studio                                 0x101d43f6c parseVMOptions + 956
24  studio                                 0x101d431a6 -[Launcher buildArgsFor:] + 150
25  studio                                 0x101d43695 -[Launcher launch] + 453
26  Foundation                          0x7ff80d14382c __NSThread__start__ + 1009
27  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80c219259 _pthread_start + 125
28  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80c214c7b thread_start + 15

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80c214c58 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80c214c58 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff80c214c58 start_wqthread + 0


Thread 3 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x000070000c2a6000  rcx: 0x000070000c2a3ab8  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000002903  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x000070000c2a3ae0  rsp: 0x000070000c2a3ab8
   r8: 0x000070000c2a3980   r9: 0x00007ff80c1d5f9b  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000246
  r12: 0x0000000000002903  r13: 0x0000003000000008  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x0000000000000016
  rip: 0x00007ff80c1e130e  rfl: 0x0000000000000246  cr2: 0x00007ff84be7a6c8
  
Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148 
Trap Number:     133


Binary Images:
    0x7ff80c1d9000 -     0x7ff80c212ff7 libsystem_kernel.dylib (*) <0c2fd2c9-777c-3355-b70f-7b1b6e9d1b0b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7ff80c275000 -     0x7ff80c70dfff com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9) <dbc459f3-81bb-398a-8f74-3f7392392bb7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
       0x101d3f000 -        0x101d46fff com.google.android.studio (2021.3) <fab7cfe6-77b4-3fd6-b5ec-bd01fd451094> /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio
    0x7ff80bee2000 -     0x7ff80bf76547 dyld (*) <0f050705-2258-3d40-b7bc-f3b35a44bbea> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7ff80c213000 -     0x7ff80c21eff7 libsystem_pthread.dylib (*) <13b5e252-77d1-31e1-888d-1c5f4426ea87> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7ff80c0e1000 -     0x7ff80c169fff libsystem_c.dylib (*) <5efaf10b-2ec1-32ed-b077-80125e552c8d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x7ff80c1c3000 -     0x7ff80c1d8ff7 libc++abi.dylib (*) <68c48086-22ee-31c9-a457-954d641b9328> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x7ff80bea6000 -     0x7ff80bee1fd8 libobjc.A.dylib (*) <aca7ef61-2853-3699-8c1f-1c0ab93ad6be> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7ff80f3d6000 -     0x7ff8103daff6 com.apple.AppKit (6.9) <817d572e-eb8c-3999-b7a0-68e1c4b47266> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
    0x7ff80d0eb000 -     0x7ff80dafcff6 com.apple.Foundation (6.9) <eca88952-d3af-357e-80d8-4d31b2dc0c26> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=402.3M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=402.3M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=618.3M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=618.3M(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Activity Tracing                   256K        1 
ColorSync                          212K       23 
CoreGraphics                         8K        2 
Foundation                          16K        1 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        1 
MALLOC                           215.4M       39 
MALLOC guard page                   32K        8 
MALLOC_NANO (reserved)           384.0M        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
STACK GUARD                       56.0M        7 
Stack                             18.5M        7 
VM_ALLOCATE                         12K        3 
VM_ALLOCATE (reserved)              12K        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
__CTF                               756        1 
__DATA                            15.5M      303 
__DATA_CONST                      13.9M      181 
__DATA_DIRTY                       652K      106 
__FONT_DATA                        2352        1 
__LINKEDIT                       181.5M        5 
__OBJC_RO                         65.1M        1 
__OBJC_RW                         1982K        2 
__TEXT                           220.8M      324 
dyld private memory                256K        1 
mapped file                       69.7M       16 
shared memory                      772K       16 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              1.2G     1051 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space   860.7M     1051 



Model: MacBookAir9,1, BootROM 1916.40.8.0.0 (iBridge: 20.16.411.0.0,0), 4 processors, Quad-Core Intel Core i5, 1.1 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 
Graphics: Intel Iris Plus Graphics, Intel Iris Plus Graphics, Built-In
Display: Color LCD, 2560 x 1600 Retina, Main, MirrorOff, Online
Display: Unknown Display, 1920 x 1080 (1080p FHD - Full High Definition), MirrorOff, Online
Memory Module: BANK 0/ChannelA-DIMM0, 8 GB, LPDDR4X, 3733 MHz, SK Hynix, H9HCNNNFBMALPR-NEE
Memory Module: BANK 2/ChannelB-DIMM0, 8 GB, LPDDR4X, 3733 MHz, SK Hynix, H9HCNNNFBMALPR-NEE
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_wifi (0x14E4, 0x870), wl0: Sep  6 2022 23:42:56 version 16.20.356.2.3.6.115 FWID 01-81f9b3db
Bluetooth: Version (null), 0 services, 0 devices, 0 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB31Bus
USB Device: USB3.0 Hub
USB Device: USB31Bus
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
USB Device: USB C Video Adaptor
USB Device: Mass Storage Device
USB Device: USB Mouse
USB Device: USB Keyboard
USB Device: T2Bus
USB Device: Touch Bar Backlight
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: Headset
USB Device: Ambient Light Sensor
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Apple T2 Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc., 86.0
```

things I have tried:

- trying different versions (even beta or canary) from official and none-official sources
- updating, uninstalling and reinstalling the app
- trying jetbrain toolbox for installation
- updating `jdk` to latest version (19)
- changing configs in `.vmoptions` file or removing it (including`-Dsun.font.layoutengine=icu`)
- removing `gradle`,`android sdk` and etc folders related to android studio

to be clear, I can not open android studio and the moment I click on the app icon the crash message is popping up.
[image: problem report for studio]

Comment: Exactly the same. Please ping me via a comment if you find a solution.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu the first answer may help.

Answer (score 6):

**Simply run it as sudo**

Open your terminal and type below command:
cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio.

Comment: How does `cd` fix the issue with an editor terminating unexpectedly?

Comment: ...just change 'cd' to 'sudo'

Comment: ...so sudo /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio

Answer (score 4):

### use no aux display (or in some cases, device)

after few days I tried to open AS and surprisingly it worked!
the only thing that caused the problem was aux display that I was using.
**I could reproduce the issue by connecting extra display and when I tried to open AS without any aux display (or without any device connected to it e.g. keyboard) it opens. (restarting needed!)**

Comment: Hmmm, I'm on MacBook and never used any external display, keyboard, mouse, or anything, but getting this error.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu open AS the moment your OS is up! lemme know if worked!

Comment: Weird enough, I tried to open AS now (without restarting) and it... just opened!

Answer (score 1):

Open your terminal and type this command:

`sudo /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio`.